# How to auto login in rails-on-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, autologin

I use devise(ruby-on-rails) for authentication, using before_filter:authenticate_user! to require user login. Now I want to skip the login operation when on Rails.env:dev while still need authentication on Rails.env:prd.
I wonder if I can auto login with a specific user(like admin) on code when the projected launched on env:dev.

```
class QueryController < ActionController::Base
    layout "query"
    before_filter :auto_login
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except =>
    [
        :show,
        :query
    ]

    def auto_login
        if Rails.env == 'dev'
            current_user = User.find_by(login: 'admin')
        end
    end
```

I wonder how authenticate_user implements to do the login action. I try to login with a user but failed.

Answer (score 1):

To login your admin user just do something like

```
current_user = User.find_by(login: 'admin')
```

But, you probably shouldn't do this. Always being an admin user in development mode is a bad idea. You should be logging in as different types of users to test your code properly.

Comment: In my case, I also had to set the role since I am using cancancan. Then these ideas allowed default user and role and no login was required for a shop floor kiosk. Thank you.